# .angular-cli.json' failed.Ensure the file is valid JSON. Error: Unexpected token ] in >JSON at position

Tags: angular, npm-install, ng-file-upload

Im install  this `npm install ng-file-upload` [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) for my project now my project getting some error,

> D:\web\ng4fbbootstrap\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:89
>               throw new InvalidConfigError(common_tags_1.stripIndent `
>               ^
>
> InvalidConfigError: Parsing 'D:\web\ng4fbbootstrap.angular-cli.json'
>   failed. Ensure the file is valid JSON. Error: Unexpected token ] in
>   JSON at position 515
>       at Function.fromConfigPath (D:\web\ng4fbbootstrap\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:89:19)
>       at Function.fromProject (D:\web\ng4fbbootstrap\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config.js:67:46)
>       at Object. (D:\web\ng4fbbootstrap\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build.js:10:35)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

**package.jason**

```
{
  "name": "ng4fbbootstrap",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
    "@types/fullcalendar": "^3.5.1",
    "angular-bootstrap-calendar": "^0.30.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.22.1",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.0.3",
    "angular-weekly-scheduler": "0.0.5",
    "ap-angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.3.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.6.2",
    "fullcalendar-ag4": "^0.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13",
    "ng-fullcalendar": "^1.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

how to fix that issue? 
please help me

Comment: `ng-file-upload` is for angularjs (v1), not for the angular version you are using

Comment: @core114 it's not the package.json that's failing to parse. But ng4fbbootstrap.angular-cli.json

Comment: ok sir thats fine now its work for me Im use this  `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem
again install `Angular`

`npm install -g @angular/cli`
now its work for me